# Proving integral is zero

Tags: definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

I want to prove that for $m,n\in \mathbb{N}$, $m\neq n$ following holds $(\cos (nx),\cos (mx))=0$ in $L_2(-\pi,\pi)$. Which means
$$\int_{-\pi}^\pi\cos(nx)\cos(mx)dx=0.$$
Is there a clever way to do this?

Comment: See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WernerFormulas.html

Comment: It would improve your Question to include an example of what you consider a not-so-clever way of demonstrating it.

Comment: You can simply say that the integral of the product of orthogonal functions is 0

Answer (score 14, accepted):

$$\cos(nx)\cos(mx) = \frac{1}{2}\left( \cos((n-m)x) - \cos((n + m)x)\right)$$

Answer (score 7):

You may write $ \cos (nx) = \dfrac{\exp (inx   ) + \exp(-inx)}{2}$ and then when calculating the integral you will end up with exponentials contributing zero.

Notice this is equivalent with Biro's way, however it is easier for me to remember the used identity using Euler's formula.

Comment: There is a typo in the $\exp(\dots)$

Comment: @SimpleArt Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

If you are in an exam and you simply can't remember the trigonometric formula used by @MichaelBiro, and you also are afraid of @clark's complex exponentials, then integrating by parts **twice** will save you (assuming $n \ne 0$):

$$\int \limits _{-\pi} ^\pi \underbrace {\cos mx} _u \underbrace {\cos nx} _{v'} \ \Bbb d x = \cos mx \frac {\sin nx} n \Bigg| _{-\pi} ^\pi - \int \limits _{-\pi} ^\pi (-m \sin mx) \frac {\sin nx} n \Bbb d x =\\
\frac m n \int \limits _{-\pi} ^\pi \underbrace{\sin mx} _u \underbrace{\sin nx} _{v'} \Bbb d x = \frac m n \left( \sin mx \frac {-\cos nx} n \Bigg| _{-\pi} ^\pi - \int \limits _{-\pi} ^\pi m \cos mx \frac {-\cos nx} n \ \Bbb d x \right) =\\
\frac {m^2} {n^2} \int \limits _{-\pi} ^\pi \cos mx \cos nx \ \Bbb d x$$

whence it follows that

$$\left( \frac {m^2} {n^2} - 1 \right) \int \limits _{-\pi} ^\pi \cos mx \cos nx \ \Bbb d x = 0$$

whence (remembering that $m \ne n$)

$$\int \limits _{-\pi} ^\pi \cos mx \cos nx \ \Bbb d x = 0 .$$

If $n = 0$ then $m \ne 0$, so just exchange $u$ and $v$.

Comment: Were not $n \ne 0, m \ne 0$ taken care of in the condition $m,n\in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: @farruhota: For most people $\Bbb N = \{ \color{red} 0, 1, 2, \dots \}$. The one without $0$ is often denoted $\Bbb N ^*$, but this notation isn't standard (since the $*$ is highly overloaded in mathematics).

Comment: I see, then you've taken care of it. One more question: isn't easier to state the function is odd, therefore its integral in $[-\pi,\pi]$ is $0$?

Comment: @farruhota: Since the integrand is the product of two *even* functions, it is itself *even*, not odd.

Comment: Yes, you are right, silly mistake. The cosines at full round (unlike $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$) take both positive and negative values, which cancel each other. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Just observe that $\cos nx \cos mx = \frac12(\cos(n+m)x + \cos(n-m)x)$.

Assuming that $n\neq \pm m$, this has an antiderivative which is a constant multiple of $\sin (n+m)x + \sin(n-m)x$, which vanishes when evaluated at each of the limits of integration.

I don't know this formula automatically, by the way. I just wrote
$$\cos nx \cos mx = \left(\frac{e^{inx}+e^{-inx}}2\right)\left(\frac{e^{imx}+e^{-imx}}2\right)$$
$$= \frac12\left(\frac{e^{i(n+m)x}+ e^{i(n-m)x}+ e^{-i(n-m)x}+e^{-i(n+m)x}}2\right)$$
$$= \frac12{}\left(\frac{e^{i(n+m)x}+e^{-i(n+m)x}}2 + \frac{e^{i(n-m)x}+e^{-i(n-m)x}}2\right)$$
$$=\frac12 (\cos (n+m)x + \cos (n-m)x)$$